# How to optimize the simplest SQL query of a very simple table?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

**Query**

`SELECT * FROM public.data`

**Table**

- id → PK Integer
- data → json
- timestamp → timestamp
- version → integer

The `data` column can have "large" values (e.g ~250kb)

**Result of query**

- Time: 4m 52s
- Nb rows: 620

---

I'm not sure what's the bottleneck here. It seems like it shouldn't take that much time to fetch only 620 rows. Perhaps the data column is what's slowing everything down?

Is there something I could do to make this query much faster? I tried using an index, but no success. As you can tell I'm no DB expert and maybe there's a low-hanging fruit solution since this is a very basic query.

Thanks for the help

---

**Edit 1**

Here's the output of `explain (analyze, buffers) select * from public.data;`

```
"Seq Scan on data  (cost=0.00..7.86 rows=619 width=34) (actual time=0.007..0.083 rows=620 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=6"
"Planning Time: 0.171 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.138 ms"
```

Here's the output of the `create table` for this table:

```
-- Table: public.data

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.data;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.data
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('data_id_seq'::regclass),
    data json NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    version integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.data
    OWNER to vxpxchlkkyyvaa;
```

Comment: Paste the output of this query into your question: `explain (analyze, buffers) select * from public.data;`. Also the SQL `create table` statement for this table.

Comment: As you want _everything_ (all rows, all columns), there is not much you can do except for throwing faster hardware on the problem.

Comment: Please include any additional information in the question itself using the edit link under the question! Let the person who requested it know via another comment with "@" + their name (no space).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with the additional info :)

Comment: Why does it matter how fast it runs? You shouldn’t be executing a select everything query often enough for a hundred milliseconds to be a problem

Comment: How do you measure "4m 52s"? The explain output shows the query completed in _under 1 millisecond_.

Comment: @mustaccio What do you mean? The `explain` query takes under 1ms. This query takes 4m 52s: `SELECT * FROM public.data`

Comment: I guess you don't realise that `explain (analyze, buffers)` actually executes the query and measures its response time, which is printed at the end of its output.

Comment: @mustaccio Got it. Well then I believe I'm doing something wrong with the `explain` query? When I'm running this query in pgAdmin4, it takes 4m 5s second to complete `SELECT * FROM public.data`. *Edit* I run both queries (`SELECT` and `EXPLAIN`) in pgAdmin4

Comment: I'd say you're doing something wrong with pgAdmin4.

Comment: I'm simply adding and removing the `explain (analyze, buffers)` part and alternating between queries. The `select` one definitely takes more time.

Comment: The only difference then is having to transfer, process, and display ~150 MB of JSON data.

Comment: This difference is experienced not only in a GUI like pgAdmin4, but also when querying programmatically. What I'm getting at is that the client is not at fault here. Perhaps the only solution at this point is better hardware for the db server?

Comment: @MaximeDupré the problem is nothing to do with the DB. It has happily done all the work to read the data and have it ready to be received by your client programs in less than a second. The problem is your design has made it necessary for large amounts of data to need transferring in one go from DB to client and however you’re doing that fetching is not that efficient (likely lots of back and forth chatter, probably due to the json datatype). Consider why you really need to grab every column of every row and it need to be fast - perhaps you ought to be caching this data somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the issue only occurred locally.

I assume that my Heroku dyno and my PG DB are in the same AWS region and have some sort of prioritized access to each other which makes the communication really fast. Indeed, on my server, it takes less than a second to make the query, whereas when I'm making the query locally (either using pgAdmin4 or programmatically), it takes ~5m.